# Implementing Authentication/Authorization on Flash Media Server

Tags: flash, authorization, cas, flash-media-server

We are using a flash media server to serve streaming media (H.264) for our application. Within the application itself we have implemented authentication ([CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas)) and authorization so only certain people can see certain videos. The problem, however, is that if the users just looked at the source they could see the external link to our flash streaming server and just send that URL out to whomever, thus by-passing our application. Is there anyway to implement security on a per video basis on the flash media server? If it could integrate with CAS, that would be even better.

The only help I've found so far is through [Adobe's site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d37a-7feb.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d37a-7fec) but was hoping someone here had a better solution.

Comment: If anyone has additional information about using token-based authentication that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Was pointed to another resource http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/digital_media_protection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Flash Media Server 3.5 * Developing an Authorization plug-in

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_Plugin/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0d662434-7fe8.html

Protect video content (Flash Media Server)

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/405/kb405456.html

Answer (score 0):

I would place lightweight proxy in front of media server like nginx. 
This would allow you to do load balancing AND any restrictions you need (you may only allow certain IPs on certain URLs).

Comment: The streams themselves will need authorization on a per stream basis, based off the application. It will not be based on IP or URL but rather the users access within the application (not on the streaming server).

Comment: Is there a way to make the proxy server call-back to a web service and verify if the user does/does not have access?